# Access 2010 VBA ADODB Recordset returns only one record

Tags: sql-server, vba, adodb

Since hours i am trying and trying, but find no solution... Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim Cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Cn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB.1"
    Cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Cn.ConnectionString = "Password=*************;" & _
    "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
    "User ID=sa;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=pA-StdVK-KalkDB_V1;" & _
    "Data Source=WINSER27"
    Cn.Open

    Rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[VIEW_Superliste_000]", Cn

    ' Me ist im Formular Name und Rs das Column im SQL Server
    Me.TeileGruppe.Value = Rs.Fields("Teilegruppe")
    Me.PlanTGrpSpanne_Stfl1.Value = Rs.Fields("Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl1")
    Me.PlanTGrpSpanne_Stfl2.Value = Rs.Fields("Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl2")
    Me.PlanTGrpSpanne_Stfl3.Value = Rs.Fields("Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl3")
    ...
    Me.Suchbegriff.Value = Rs.Fields("Suchbegriff")
    Me.Selektion.Value = Rs.Fields("Selektion")
    Me.Katalogartikel.Value = Rs.Fields("Katalogartikel")
    Me.Sparte.Value = Rs.Fields("Sparte")

    Dim i As Long
    i = 0

    Do Until Rs.EOF
        i = i + 1
        Rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    Rs.Close


ExitSub:
    Set Rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

With ... i short the code here on stackoverflow, that it is not so long!!!

Why get i only one record???

Comment: As far as I understand your code, you are loading the first recordset in the form, then looping into all the records without doing anything...

Comment: @Vincent Why i am loading only the first? Please help me... in the Moment i understand nothing :-(  I can't place the Do above the Rs.Open !!??

Comment: How are we supposed to understand your code if you don't?

Comment: `msgbox i` after `rs.close` would show you the number of records you have, you presumably only see 1 record as you only set the `.value` of the controls once.

Comment: @Gareth you're right but today is really not my day. of course mine is loop in the nothing went...

Comment: now the Loop is on the right place and it is how your were wrote. i overwrite always the first and then only the last is recorded!!! thx

Comment: @AlexK. i tried .Value both but no effect. I set the MsgBox i and the are more than one rows...

Comment: @All                                                                                                                    Do Until Rs.EOF = True
        i = i + 1
        Me.TeileGruppe.Value = Rs.Fields("Teilegruppe").Value
        ...
        Me.Sparte.Value = Rs.Fields("Sparte").Value
        Rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    But only the last is in the datarecord!!! Why the loop is now correct!? Or not!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the code to something like this:

```
Rs.MoveFirst
Do Until Rs.EOF

Me.TeileGruppe.Value = Rs.Fields("Teilegruppe")
Me.PlanTGrpSpanne_Stfl1.Value = Rs.Fields("Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl1")
Me.PlanTGrpSpanne_Stfl2.Value = Rs.Fields("Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl2")
Me.PlanTGrpSpanne_Stfl3.Value = Rs.Fields("Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl3")
...
Me.Suchbegriff.Value = Rs.Fields("Suchbegriff")
Me.Selektion.Value = Rs.Fields("Selektion")
Me.Katalogartikel.Value = Rs.Fields("Katalogartikel")
Me.Sparte.Value = Rs.Fields("Sparte")

Rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

In your code, you loaded the first recordset into your form and then you looped through all the recordsets, with this code, you loop through the records and load each on into the form.
But each time the value of the textboxes will be replaced, so you will most likely only see the last record.

Comment: THX, but i have it not finaly yet

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, try to explain what you want to do.

Comment: Access is only the frontend. SQL Server 2008 completly the backend. On the Server i have a view with 10000 rows. When i link the view with ODBC, the performance is very awful!!! So i want to get the data with the ABODB.

Comment: Should i better use DAO with snapshot?

Comment: You could try it, snapshot should be a lot faster